# Como usar ancora no vuejs/vue-loader?

Tags: vue.js, webpack

Estou criando um projeto com vuejs webpack (vue-loader) e recentemente me deparei com um problema, não consigo ancorar nenhuma tag, pois o vue entende que ao usar o hash #, vc esta querendo direcionar para uma rota...
Alguem sabe como resolver isso ?

**Quero que quando houver um click na tag `<a>`, a pagina seja ancorada para a div de baixo:**

```
<a href="#ancora"> Teste </a>

<div id="ancora" style="margin-top: 1000px">
   <h1> Oi, eu sou uma div </h1>
</div>
```

No href da tag `<a>` ja tentei colocar das seguintes formas:  `#ancora`, `/endereço-url#ancora` , `/endereço-url/#ancora` , `/#ancora`.
Mas tudo sem sucesso

Comment: Talvez isto ajude, http://stackoverflow.com/q/40341939/3162303

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descobri que ao usar a tag `<router-link>` ao invés da tag `<a>`, é possível resolver este problema, alem de também resolver outros problemas como o de links-ativos por exemplo.

No caso ficaria assim:

```
<router-link to="#ancora"> Teste </router-link>

<div id="ancora" style="margin-top: 1000px">
   <h1> Oi, eu sou uma div </h1>
</div>
```

Muito obrigado a todos pela ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que esteja utilizando o vueRouter, caso sim, é preciso alterar a forma como a função scrollBehavior se comporta. O exemplo abaixo demonstra como navegar até o elemento na página em vez de mudar de "página".

```
new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    scrollBehavior: function(to, from, savedPosition) {
        if (to.hash) {
            return {selector: to.hash}
        } else {
            return { x: 0, y: 0 }
        }
    },
    routes: [
        {path: '/', component: abcView},
        // your routes
    ]
});
```

A documentação pode ser encontrada no link:
http://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/scroll-behavior.html

O exemplo foi retirado do seguinte link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40341939/how-to-create-anchor-tags-with-vue-router

Answer (score 1):

Olá

Veja uma outra solução, talvez seja mais simples.

```
    <a v-bind:href="ancoraTeste" @click="showAlert">{{textLink}} </a>

    <div id="ancora" style="margin-top: 500px">
        <h1> Oi, eu sou uma div </h1>
    </div>
```

```
   <script>
       new Vue({
         el:'#app',
         data:{
            textLink:'Link com Ancora',
            ancoraTeste: '#ancora'
         },
         methods:{

             showAlert: function(event){
                alert('show')
             }

         }
       });
    </script>
```